# Fatal Error: DOMDocument not found after Zend Server CE Update

Tags: php, windows-7, zend-framework2, domdocument, zend-server-ce

I'm working with Zend Server CE on a Windows 7 (64bit) System.

I'm developing a website with Zend Framework 2.0. In this website I use DOMDocument to analyse an external website (given by URL).

I started this project with Zend Framework 1.12 and Zend Server CE 4 (PHP 5.2). Now I installed the Zend Server CE 5.6.0 (apache2.2, PHP 5.3.14, ZF2-Support). I rebuild my project with ZF2.0. Everything works fine...except one function.

I get this Error-Message (php-error.log), when I try to instantiate DOMDocument:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\DOMDocument' not found in
_Path_\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\SearchbarController.php on line 81
```

With PHP 5.2 (ZF 1.12) and Zend Server CE 4, this function worked perfectly. But now...without any change, it throws this error.

The dom-extension and the xml-extension are built-in in PHP 5.3. I checked phpinfo and my php.ini, that these extensions are running.

I read, that i should install php-xml. But dom, xml and libxml are running...why should i re-install them?

I don't know, why DOMDocument could not be instantiated after upgrading the Zend Server CE. May be, that the ZF2.0 is a possible reason for this error. But I can't find anything pointing to this.

Comment: Will it be fixed if you instantiate your object with `$dom = new \DOMDocument(...)` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, it's introduction of namespaces (feature of PHP 5.3 quite heavily used by ZF2 - but not ZF 1.x) that caused this bug. With this line...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(...)
```

... only the currently imported namespace is checked for this class by ZF. And it results in failure, because `DOMDocument` class actually belongs to the global namespace.

The solution is simple, when you see the reason: use the `global namespace specifier` - `\` symbol - in front of the class name. Like this:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument(...)
```